# How to nest the results of a second mysql within each row of a JSON object?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am performing a query which returns a list of comments as shown below:

```
$sQuery = "
        select cp_comments.*,users.user_login, users.user_url, users.display_name, users.ID as avatar, cp_comments.id as replies

         from ".$wpdb->prefix."cp_comments cp_comments
            left join ".$wpdb->prefix."users users on users.ID=cp_comments.uid
            where songid='$id'
            order by cp_comments.id asc
    ";
    $result1 = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

I then loop through the results and encode a json array like so:

```
/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(

    "comments" => array()

);


while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $result1, MYSQL_ASSOC ) )
{

    $row = array();

    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {

        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "playtime" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'playtime' column */
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) / $duration * 100;
        }           
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] == "avatar" )
        {
            /* Special output to render Avatar by user id */
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = commentplayer_get_user_avatar($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]);
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[$aColumns[$i]] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }

    $output['comments'][] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($output);
```

This produces a JSON response as shown:-

```
{ "comments" : [ { "avatar" : "http://www.songbanc.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg",
        "body" : "More tests....",
        "display_name" : "admin",
        "id" : "26",
        "playtime" : 36.206896551699998,
        "posttime" : "2011-10-08 11:11:55",
        "cid" : "26",
        "songid" : "30",
        "uid" : "1",
        "user_login" : "admin",
        "user_url" : "http://www.songbanc.com/members/admin/"

      },
      { "avatar" : "http://www.songbanc.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg",
        "body" : "test comment",
        "display_name" : "admin",
        "id" : "70",
        "playtime" : 29.597701149399999,
        "posttime" : "2011-10-13 15:51:01",
        "cid" : "70",
        "songid" : "30",
        "uid" : "1",
        "user_login" : "admin",
        "user_url" : "http://www.songbanc.com/members/admin/"
      },
      { "avatar" : "http://www.songbanc.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg",
        "body" : "Another genius comment....",
        "display_name" : "admin",
        "id" : "71",
        "playtime" : 48.8505747126,
        "posttime" : "2011-10-13 15:55:38",
        "cid" : "71",
        "songid" : "30",
        "uid" : "1",
        "user_login" : "admin",
        "user_url" : "http://www.songbanc.com/members/admin/"
      }
    ] }
```

However I need to retrieve the 'replies' to each comment (which are stored in a seperate table and nest them within the same JSON object.

So that the final encoded JSON is output like so:-

```
{ "comments" : [ { "avatar" : "http://www.songbanc.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg",
        "body" : "More tests....",
        "display_name" : "admin",
        "id" : "26",
        "playtime" : 36.206896551699998,
        "posttime" : "2011-10-08 11:11:55",
        "cid" : "26",
        "songid" : "30",
        "uid" : "1",
        "user_login" : "admin",
        "user_url" : "http://www.songbanc.com/members/admin/"
        "cid": "1",
        "replies" : [ { "cid" : "26",
                        "body" : "test reply",
                        "posttime" : "2011-10-08 11:11:55"
                      }]

      },
```

I can't seem to work out how to nest the results of a second mysql query into each row (assuming any replies exist at all)

The query I would like to run to return the replies for a given comment (linked as 'cid' in the two tables) is:-

```
$sql = "select cp_replies.*,users.user_login, users.user_url, users.display_name, users.ID as avatar 

    from ".$wpdb->prefix."cp_replies cp_replies
                left join ".$wpdb->prefix."users users on users.ID=cp_replies.uid
                where cp_replies.cid= $cid
                order by cp_replies.id asc";

$result2 = mysql_query( $sql, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

With the variable $cid needing to be passed dynamically to the query depending on which 'cid' of each row for th first query. (I hope that makes sense).

I tried creating a seperate function containing the query, passed it the 'cid' as variable but kept getting 'null' returned when I tried to retrieve the array.

I really am stuck here guys and truly hope someone can help me.

EDIt:

Having made the changes suggested by StuR, it is clear that I am getting closer but it's still not as intended.  My JSON (assuming I have implemented his suggestions correctly, is now as follows:-

```
{ "comments" : [ { "avatar" : "http://www.songbanc.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg",
        "body" : "comment at 0:48",
        "display_name" : "admin",
        "id" : "2",
        "playtime" : 17.977528089900002,
        "posttime" : "2011-09-28 14:38:41",
        "songid" : "24",
        "uid" : "1",
        "user_login" : "admin",
        "user_url" : "http://www.songbanc.com/members/admin/"
      },
      { "replies" : { "body" : "haha reply",
            "cid" : "2",
            "id" : "1",
            "posttime" : "2011-09-28 15:14:56",
            "uid" : "1",
            "user_login" : "admin"
          } },
      { "avatar" : "http://www.songbanc.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg",
        "body" : "asdasd",
        "display_name" : "admin",
        "id" : "3",
        "playtime" : 0.74906367041199995,
        "posttime" : "2011-09-28 14:43:11",
        "songid" : "24",
        "uid" : "1",
        "user_login" : "admin",
        "user_url" : "http://www.songbanc.com/members/admin/"
      },
      { "replies" : { "body" : "haha reply",
            "cid" : "2",
            "id" : "1",
            "posttime" : "2011-09-28 15:14:56",
            "uid" : "1",
            "user_login" : "admin"
          } },
      { "avatar" : "http://www.songbanc.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/8bb11e958a26913e2c13393014e854d5-bpthumb.jpg",
        "body" : "test",
        "display_name" : "admin",
        "id" : "10",
        "playtime" : 36.329588014999999,
        "posttime" : "2011-10-06 14:15:12",
        "songid" : "24",
        "uid" : "1",
        "user_login" : "admin",
        "user_url" : "http://www.songbanc.com/members/admin/"
      },
      { "replies" : { "body" : "haha reply",
            "cid" : "2",
            "id" : "1",
            "posttime" : "2011-09-28 15:14:56",
            "uid" : "1",
            "user_login" : "admin"
          } }
    ] }
```

Any builds on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output['comments'][] = $row;
```

This is creating a nested array under 'comments' for each row it loops, so before encoding it to JSON your array structure would look something like:

```
$output['comments'][]['id'] = 26;
$output['comments'][]['songid'] = 30;
```

So you want to put your replies into:

```
$output['comments'][]['replies'] = $replies;
```

What I would do is put your second query within your while loop, and then do this:

```
while ( $replies = mysql_fetch_array( $result2, MYSQL_ASSOC ) )
{
    $output['comments'][$cid]['replies'][] = $replies;
}
```

And change in your first while:

```
$output['comments'][] = $row;
```

to

```
$output['comments'][$cid] = $row;
```

Comment: Thanks StuR, you're definately on the right lines, but it's not quite there yet unfortunately.  I am now returning the replies however it seems to be only the first row of the query, repeated for each row of the while loop, also they are not nested within the comment objects, instead they seem to be merged.  I'm not sure I am describing this correctly, I will edit my question with a copy of the JSON I am now getting.  Thanks for your help so far however!

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you use the $cid as the key for the nested array. And then loop through your replies and add them to $output['comments'][$cid]['replies'][]... that should work.

Comment: ..or better yet use an incremental value for the key, because if you set ['comments'][], and ['comments'][]['replies'] it will create two nested arrays unless you define a key.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks a lot StuR, it's much appreciated.  A genuinely throrough and effective answer. :-)